# Change CSS animation-duration in continuous rotate

Tags: javascript, html, css, rotation, css-animations

I have an earth globe and it rotates with duration of 20s. When user clicks on the globe, it's duration time changes for 1s to duration of 2s. The problem is here that when duration time changes, globe rotation position is changed. I want to have a continuous rotation even on changing duration.

My code is here. Try multiple times by clicking on the globe.

```js
function onGlobeClick() {
    var g = document.getElementById('globe');
  g.classList.add('fast');
  setTimeout(() => g.classList.remove('fast'), 1000);
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
}

.globe {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: url(https://web.archive.org/web/20150807125159if_/http://www.noirextreme.com/digital/Earth-Color4096.jpg);
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-size: 600px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 7px #fff4, inset 0px 0px 20px 7px #0008;
    animation-name: rotate;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-name: rotate;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.globe.fast {
    animation-duration: 2s;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
}
.globe:not(.fast) {
    animation-duration: 20s;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 20s;
}

@keyframes rotate {
    from {
        background-position: 0px 0px;
    }
    to {
        background-position: 600px 0px;
    }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes rotate {
    from {
        background-position: 0px 0px;
    }
    to {
        background-position: 600px 0px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id='globe' class='globe' onclick='onGlobeClick()' >
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By setting the animation-duration, you are effectively creating a new animation. In order to avoid this, manipulate the speed of the existing animation with JS using the [playbackRate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Animation/playbackRate) property.

```js
function onGlobeClick() {
    var g = document.getElementById('globe');
    
    var a = g.getAnimations()[0];
    a.playbackRate = 10;

    setTimeout(() => (a.playbackRate = 1), 1000);
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
}

.globe {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: url(https://web.archive.org/web/20150807125159if_/http://www.noirextreme.com/digital/Earth-Color4096.jpg);
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-size: 600px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 7px #fff4, inset 0px 0px 20px 7px #0008;
    animation-name: rotate;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-duration: 20s;
}

@keyframes rotate {
    from {
        background-position: 0px 0px;
    }
    to {
        background-position: 600px 0px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id='globe' class='globe' onclick='onGlobeClick()' >
</div>
```